# Getting 'Day of Year' array from a numpy array inputs in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have data in numpy array that include Year, Month, and Day as columns,
I want to calculate the Julian day or the 'Day of Year' (DOY) that should be a numpy array as well.

The formula to calculate DOY is:

```
import datetime
y = 2017
m = 4
d = 13
DOY = int(dt.datetime(y, m, d).strftime('%j')
```

*it will print 103*

Assuming we have `y_ar`, `m_ar`, and `d_ar` as the arrays of years, months, and days,

**I tried this:**

```
julians = int(dt.datetime(y_ar, m_ar, d_ar).strftime('%j'))
```

it gives my `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`
 I tried something else *which succeeded*:

```
julians = np.array(map(lambda (y, m, d): int(dt.datetime(y, m, d).strftime('%j')), zip(y_ar, m_ar, d_ar)))
```

Although it gives me what I want, but I feel that it is a bit time consuming to take element by element, then to output a list, then to convert it back no numpy array!

Can anyone help me determine why the error occurs, and wheather there is a better, faster way to do so?

***Sample arrays to help to test the solution:***

```
y_ar = np.array([1990, 2000, 2015, 2017])
m_ar = np.array([5, 8, 1, 12])
d_ar = np.array([13, 7, 30, 29])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `datetime` in combination with numpy arrays will be slow in general because it will create arrays with `dtype=object`. However, starting with version 1.7.0 numpy has a builtin [`datetime64` type](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html).

It is a bit strange to use, but this seems to work:

#### original solution (list comprehension instead of map)

```
import datetime as dt

y_ar = np.array([1990, 2000, 2015, 2017])
m_ar = np.array([5, 8, 1, 12])
d_ar = np.array([13, 7, 30, 29])

julians_ref = np.array([int(dt.datetime(y, m, d).strftime('%j')) for y, m, d in zip(y_ar, m_ar, d_ar)])
```

#### native numpy solution

```
y_ar = (y_ar - 1970).astype('M8[Y]')
m_ar = (m_ar - 1).astype('m8[M]')
d_ar = (d_ar - 1).astype('m8[D]')

date_ar = y_ar + m_ar + d_ar  # full date
julians = date_ar - y_ar + 1  # days since first day of the year

print(julians_ref)  # [133 220  30 363]
print(julians)  # [133 220  30 363]
```

---

> ```
> julians = int(dt.datetime(y_ar, m_ar, d_ar).strftime('%j'))
> ```
>
> it gives my TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars I tried

This is because `datetime.datetime` is not aware of numpy arrays. is expects a scalar (=a single) value for year, month, and day. When the interpreter tries to convert an array into a scalar this fails, unless the array is equivalent to a scalar (it has only one element).

Comment: Thank you for your efforts and detailed reply.